# what is flutter app default path in macos?

Tags: flutter, dart

Use flutter dev app with macos desktop.

One local file: test1.md

In Dart code, I cann't find local file: test1.md
try

```dart
print(readText("test1.md"));
```

Exception has occurred:

```sh
FileSystemException (FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'test1.md' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2))
```

```dart
print(Directory.current);
```

Output:

```sh
flutter: Directory: '/Users/jiangzhixiang/Library/Containers/com.example.enjoywork/Data'
```

How to find local file?

Comment: This file contains in folder that printed by `print(Directory.current)`? If this file must be in an app by default, you can place the file to an assets folder and read it as asset.

Comment: assets:
    - assets

very good!

Comment: Good? Are you loading a file from assets?

Comment: assets is good, but desktop, mobile also have some code to adapt


The network may be better adapted to different platforms

Comment: Where do you store the files you open from the app?

Comment: final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
use this function!

Comment: And a file contains in Documents directory? Can you add `readText` function to the question?